# How can I change my AngularJS routes to file?param1=a&param2=b format?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, angular-ui-router

I need to change an existing AngularJS application from using URLs in the format:

```
example.com/thePage/#/section/1/subsection/1
```

To making the section & subsection parameters readable by the server with a format like so:

```
example.com/thePage?section=1&subsection=1
```

The environment does not offer something like mod_rewrite, so I need to change the routing in Angular to make it handle & generate these URLs.  I believe I can do this using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` however I’m not sure how to proceed from there.  I’ve tried updating the existing routing to something like the below, however it fails to return a view (as if the routing isn’t working.

```
$stateProvider  
            .state('section', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '?section',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        template: '<h3></h3>'
                    },
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: constants.baseUrl + 'views/section.html',
                        controller: 'sectionCtrl',
                        resolve: {

                            section: ['sectionervice', '$stateParams',
                                function (sectionervice, $stateParams) {
                                    return sectionervice.getsection($stateParams);
                }],
                            subsection: ['sectionervice', '$stateParams',
                                function (sectionervice, $stateParams) {
                                    return sectionervice.getsubsection($stateParams);
                }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('section.detail.subsection', {
                url: '&subsection=:sectionId',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: constants.baseUrl + 'views/section.detail.subsection.html',
                        controller: 'DictionaryCtrl'
                    }
                }
            });
```

It seems that `$stateProvider` may only work with the forward-slash(/) parameter delimiter.  Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: never tried it, but i am thinking of something like overriding the ngRoute service ?

Comment: An interesting question, but why would you want to do this in production code? Usually the "Angular state" is nothing your server needs to know or should know; your app should assemble itself in the given state on the client.

Answer (score 0):

In the ui-router website has a simple example of you trying to do.

Maybe you can do the same thing, see the RouteProvider and StateProvider settings.

url: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/app/app.js

In the server side you can retrieve the url, so you can get your parameters.

[Edit]

About `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` you can do this and do the settings in route and state providers too, that don't interfere in functionality